# How do I make my image go from one to another while it's being clicked, and once it gets released it follows a link?

Tags: html, web

I want to have the not clicked image first, and then when clicked (as long as it's been pressed [not hover]) I want it to have the other image, but once it gets released, it should follow a link. Is this possible, if so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you can use the OnClick as a button, but I need to use it as an image, which is why I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with javascirpt it is easy: 
put the image in a div.
you need something like (not tested allright?):

---

```
var firstclicked = false;    
var released = false;

var image = document.getElementById("yourImage")
image.onclick = function ()
{
    if(firstclicked == false)
    {
       var image = document.getElementById("yourImage");
       image.src = "directorynewimage/pathnewimage";
       firstclicked = true 
    }
 }
image.onmouseup = function()
{   
    if (firstclicked == true && released == false)
    {
       var image = document.getElementById("yourImage");
       image.parent.innerHTML = "<a href=\"yourhref\">HREF</a>";
       released=true; 
    }
 }
```

---

Allright?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'll do some digging around for JSC, since I'm not that familiar with it. But I'll figure out were to place it, and fix any kinks it has. Thanks